# ReSharper 5.x, HashSet Contains(), and "Possible 'null' assignment"

Tags: c#, null, resharper, contains, hashset

This code outputs `True`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Default
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<string> foo = new HashSet<string>();
        foo.Add(null);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Contains(null));
    }
}
```

The `null` in my Contains() call has a blue squiggle under it, with the following warning:

> Possible 'null' assignment to entity
>   marked with 'NotNull' attribute

When I suspend ReSharper, the warning goes away.

Why is this warning occurring?  Given that I can *add* null to a HashSet, what's broken about my wanting to check for null *in* a HashSet?

**EDIT:** .NET 3.5, VS2010

Comment: ReSharper seems to be broken. Everything else seems fine: Your code runs without exception, Reflector does not show any null check or any NonNull attribute for HashSet<T>.Add or HashSet<T>.Contains.

Comment: should you really be adding Null to a HashSet?

Comment: In my real code, the Contains(null) is in a specification that verifies that null, in fact, has *not* been added to a HashSet in a moment when the developer might be tempted to do so.

Comment: A bug in Resharper! Heaven forbid! never seen that before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a bug in Resharper.  The `HashSet<T>` type is constructed to handle `null` values.  This is evident by examining the code in reflector.  In particular the `InternalGetHashCode` method which has an explicit check for `null` and provides a default hash code of 0.

The one case where this could potentially turn up a problem is for custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` instances passed to the `HashSet<T>` which do not account for `null` values.  I'd say this is fairly rare though as `null` checks are part of the standard equality pattern for reference types in .Net.

Note: To be clear, I'm certainly not encouraging people to add `null` to their collection.  I would in fact encourage the opposite.  Just pointing out that for whatever reason `HashSet<T>` seems to explicitly allow for this scenario.

Comment: Just because you can add Null, doesn't necessarily mean its a good idea ;)

Comment: @Mitch, I didn't say this was a great idea just that `HashSet<T>` plainly thinks bad code should be allowed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this *might* be because the `HashSet<T>.Contains` method is an implementation of `ICollection<T>.Contains`.

Other implementations of `ICollection<T>` might not allow nulls.

Whether this is the case or not, there's no reason why the ReSharper ruleset couldn't be refined to not flag this as a potential error.